# Aligning <input> and <option> tags the same way

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to make a `<form>` where all `<input>` and `<select>` options are aligned like this desired result: [image: desired result]

However, this is my result: [image: my result]

As you can see, the text `<input>` are aligned correctly, but the drop down doesn't line up with them. My code is below.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="survey-form">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="name">* Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="email">* Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="number">*Age:</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" id="number" required class="input-field" placeholder="Age">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="role">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
      <select name="role" id="role" class="input-select">
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="full-time-job">Full Time Job</option>
    </div>
    <option value="full-time-learner">Full Time Learner</option>
    <option value="prefer-not-to-say">Prefer not to say</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

**CSS**:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-field {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  height: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.input-select {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I have attempted to adjust the `justify-content`, `align-items`, `display`, and the other relevant CSS but nothing seemed to get my `<select>` and `<input>` to be lined up together.

Comment: You need to use a set width on the label to do that with flexbox especially as your rows are all independent. Essentially, you may need to refactor your HTML.

Comment: Alternatively, just give the `select` extra `margin-right` since you have fixed widths - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/droKYR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVXygZ)

Starting from your code a short method could be to:

1- Add a left/right margin to the form and assign both a `width` and a `max-width`, e.g.

```
#survey-form {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

2- Give an equal `flex-basis` on `label` and `input`/`select` fields. Also assign `box-sizing: border-box`

```
.row > * {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

3- Align the labels to the right

```
.row label {
  text-align: right;
}
```